# Как правильно сделать атомарно действия: INSERT в Transactions; SELECT SUM([sum]) из Transactions; UPDATE Wallets

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица транзакций `[billing].[Transactions]` в нее пишутся денежные транзакции "зачесленно или списанно N рублей".

Есть таблица кошелек `billing.Wallets` в ней хранится состояние текущего баланса. Баланс вычисляется на основание сумм транзакций из таблицы `[billing].[Transactions]`.

Мой SQL код:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

INSERT INTO [billing].[Transactions]
    ([Id],[AccountOwnerId], [PaymentDateTime],[Sum])
VALUES
    (NEWID(), @AccountOwnerId, @Date, @Sum)

DECLARE @TotalSum int
SELECT @TotalSum = SUM([Sum])
    FROM [billing].[Transactions]
WHERE [AccountOwnerId] = @AccountOwnerId AND [PaymentDateTime] <= @Date

UPDATE billing.Wallets
    SET TotalSum = @TotalSum
WHERE AccountOwnerId = @AccountOwnerId

COMMIT;
```

Данный код периодически под нагрузкой выдает исключение что произошел deadlock: `транзакция стала жертвой другой транзакции`

Начал разбираться и накопал следущую ситуацию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уровни изоляций все перебробывал результат тот же.
Подскажи какие есть хорошие практики для решения подобных задач ?

Comment: А почему Вы не хотите выполнить обновление обычным AFTER UPDATE триггером?

Comment: Здравсвуйте Akina, спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, а использовать триггер - это бэст практис для такого рода задач ?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `WITH (UPDLOCK)` в запрос выбора суммы. И как дела с индексами? Есть индекс по AccountOwnerId, PaymentDateTime?

Comment: А `@TotalSum` точно _int_ должен быть, а не _decimal_ какой-нибудь?

Comment: Да i-one вы правы я ошибся, там decimal. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте индекс на таблице `[billing].[Transactions]` - такой, чтобы он позволял блокировать записи для конкретного аккаунта, например:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Transactions_1 ON [billing].[Transactions] ([AccountOwnerId])
    INCLUDE ([PaymentDateTime], [Sum]);
```

Затем в транзакции блокируйте диапазон записей для аккаунта `[AccountOwnerId] = @AccountOwnerId` от изменений, чтобы другая транзакция не могла вмешаться:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

DECLARE @TotalSum decimal(...); -- тут укажите нужную точность типа
SELECT @TotalSum = SUM([Sum])
    FROM [billing].[Transactions] WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, INDEX (IX_Transactions_1))
WHERE [AccountOwnerId] = @AccountOwnerId;

INSERT INTO [billing].[Transactions]
    ([Id],[AccountOwnerId], [PaymentDateTime],[Sum])
VALUES
    (NEWID(), @AccountOwnerId, @Date, @Sum);

UPDATE billing.Wallets
    SET TotalSum = COALESCE(@TotalSum + @Sum, @Sum) -- в предположении, что @Sum не NULL
WHERE AccountOwnerId = @AccountOwnerId;

COMMIT;
```

Это для уровня изоляции по-умолчанию (т.е. `READ COMMITTED`). Если уровень изоляции `SERIALIZABLE`, то `HOLDLOCK` указывать необязательно.

Условие `[PaymentDateTime] <= @Date` из запроса для подсчёта суммы на мой взгляд надо убрать, ведь если транзакция с более поздней `@Date` исполнится раньше, то последующая транзакция с более ранней `@Date` исказит баланс.

Если `@Date` по смыслу - текущая дата, то можно вообще назначать её по факту вставки данных в таблицу (вместо `@Date` в `INSERT` использовать `SYSDATETIME()` либо `SYSUTCDATETIME()`).

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение мне помогло!

Comment: @MaxKapustin, Условие `[PaymentDateTime] <= @Date` из запроса для подсчёта суммы на мой взгляд надо убрать, ведь если транзакция с более поздней `@Date` исполнится раньше, то последующая транзакция с более ранней `@Date` исказит баланс.